# Blank category page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, adminhtml, category

I am having strange issue I have edited one category and saved the data and I got a blank page as seen in the screenshot. I have cleared cache and also session and I have enabled the `error_reporting` but its showing nothing.

Please help.

---

### [image]

Comment: Do all the tabs look empty? Do you have anything in var/log?

Comment: no the product tab seems alright. no i haven't found anything in var/log..

Comment: Please confirm that your error reporting is set to `E_ALL^E_STRICT` (see *index.php*), `display_errors` is `true` and that error logging is enabled in the Default Configuration Scope in System > Configuration > Developer.

Comment: i have set every setting that you have described here but i am not getting any error only a blank page as showing in screenshot.

Comment: A php error is thrown. If you have developer mode enabled and logging is active, you have to see an error.

Comment: You could check your apache logs to be sure, if there is an error there u mightve done your configuration on display errors wrong.

Comment: It is most likely related to an extension you installed. Try disabling any category related extensions.

Comment: @SaveTheMage you were absolutely right this happens due to one category extension.! Thanks savTheMage and all of you guys who commented here..

Comment: I have undeleted answer by @SaveTheMage. Please accept it and make a comment with the name of extension which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely related to an extension you installed. Try disabling any category related extensions.

Comment: I had the issue with `Enhanced Admin Grids (+ Editor)` after applying some pathces to Magento. After updating the module to the latest version the category pages worked fine. but your answer certainly pointed me in the right direction (this was on CE 1.7 btw)

Answer (score 1):

After you open category edit page, one AJAX request performs and category tab contents refreshes. Open firebug panel and check if this Ajax request take a normally content or what kind of response returned. If response is ok, you should debug UI javascript to find the point of error.

Answer (score -1):

Just spend 2 days looking for a problem and it Was so simple I couldn't guess.

The response is json encoded and there was a character misencoded in translations. One character wrong encoded and json response is empty.

Debug at:
app/code/core/mage/adminhtml/controllers/catalog/category/CategoryController.php